# Create only one object for a class and reuse same object

Tags: java

I want to create only one object of an class and reuse the same object over and over again.
Is there any efficient way to do this.

How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you have an example class?

Comment: @AjayGopalShrestha if the question has been answered to your satisfaction, please mark the appropriate answer as accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```java
public final class MySingleton {
    private static volatile MySingleton instance;

    private MySingleton() {
        // TODO: Initialize
        // ...
    }

    /**
      * Get the only instance of this class.
      *
      * @return the single instance.
      */
    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new MySingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that was just embarrassing.

Comment: There's no need to make the entire method synchronized. See the example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Lazy_initialization

Comment: Is it advisable or overkill to mark the class as final so it cannot be extended?

Comment: Updated with recommendations here. It's a tad complex for a beginner now, though.

Comment: @AjayGopalShrestha Think twice before going for a singleton. [They are evil in most situations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300655/whats-alternative-to-singleton).

Comment: Or you could use an `enum` with three lines. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is generally implemented with the [Singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java) but the situations where it is actually required are quite rare and this is not an innocuous decision.

You should consider [alternative solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300655/whats-alternative-to-singleton) before making a decision.

This other post about [why static variables can be evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil) is also an interesting read (a singleton is a static variable).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to create a class with one one instance is to use an `enum`

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE
}
```

You can compare this with Steve Taylor's answer to see how much simple it is than alternatives.

BTW: I would only suggest you use stateless singletons.  If you want stateful singletons you are better off using dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the [Singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832297/java-singleton-pattern) - basically you prevent construction with a private constructor and "get" the instance with a static synchronized getter that will create the single instance, if it doesn't exist already.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

There is a design pattern called Singleton. If you implement it, you will get to what you need.

Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to see different ways to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Read the wikipedia article and you will find examples of how it can be implemented in Java.

Perhaps you'd also care to learn more about Design Patterns, then I'd suggest you read the book ["Head First Design Patterns"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) or [the original Design Patterns book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634988) by Erich Gamma et al (the former provides Java examples, the latter doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its called a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class. You create one and only instance and use it throughout your  code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).