# Neo4j get multiple database instances across classes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, neo4j

I am using Neo4j for storing nodes and need to access the Neo4j database across classes which should all be able to connect concurrently to the database.

I currently use

```
    public void setUp()
    {
        //deleteFileOrDirectory(new File(FILESYSTEM_DB));
        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(FILESYSTEM_DB);
        indexManager = graphDb.index();
        index = indexManager.forNodes("indexNodes");
        registerShutdownHook();
    }
```

to create the database and connect to it, however next time another class tries to run a similar method (or another instance of the same class calls the same setUp() method) I get a quite reasonable

**"Error Obtaining Lock (org.neo4j.kernal.StoreLockException)".**

How can I check if database is running and if not call newEmbeddedDatabase(FILESYSTEM_DB) otherwise connect to the running instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure variables `graphDb` and others are not local variables but fields of an instance of some class `Neo4jConnection`. Then, create single instance of that class (singleton), run `setUp()` once and use that connection whenever you need access the database. How to manage that singleton, depends on your environment (do you use Spring?). Simplest way is to have a static variable referring that singleton. Read [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832297](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832297/java-singleton-pattern) and other discussions marked with [java+singleton tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+singleton)

Comment: I'm using JSF and kind of got it working with a singleton as you suggested. I wanted however to see a way to start a server instance and let all clients connect to it via an URI without using a singleton

Comment: which clients do you mean - browsers or client connection objects inside the web server? Browsers can only connect via URI, and cannot access singletons directly anyway.