# Make 'static' class observable

Tags: java, android, static, observable, observers

I have a class `Settings` with static methods which I use to save and load my data. This is for example the `Save()` method:

```
public static void Save(SETTING_KEY key, String value)
{
    SharedPreferences sp = _context.getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

    editor.putString(key.toString(), value);
    editor.commit();    
}
```

Now I'd like to make the class `Settings` observable. The problem is that extending my Settings-class from Observable does not work, as I don't instantiate this class as I only use its static methods.

Is there any easy way to make this static class observable?

Comment: the notions of staticity and heritance do not really work on the same plan, anyway. but it does not prevent you from having a list of observers and notifying them when you do something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your own observer mechanism. Simple implementation below

```
public interface Observer {
    void onSettingsChanged(String key, String value);
}

private static Observer observer;
public static void setObserver(Observer observer_) {
    observer = observer_;
}

public static void Save(SETTING_KEY key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sp = _context.getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

    editor.putString(key.toString(), value);
    editor.commit();
    if (observer != null) {
        observer.onSettingsChanged(key, value);
    }
}
```

You could also use a `List<Observer>` if you need more than 1 and you can also use some sort of event bus ([e.g. Otto](https://github.com/square/otto)) system to publish events without having to provide a direct observer mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a Singleton pattern? ([Java Singleton Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832297/java-singleton-pattern))

That way, you can extend observable.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine a singleton with static methods.

```
class Settings extends Observable {
    private static Settings instance;
    private static synchronized Settings getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new Settings();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void Save(SETTING_KEY key, String value)
    {
        SharedPreferences sp = _context.getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

        editor.putString(key.toString(), value);
        editor.commit();
        getInstance().notifyObservers(value); // or whatever
    }

    // can't override addObserver with a static method, so make a new method instead
    public static void addObserverStatic(Observer observer) {
        getInstance().addObserver(observer);
    }
}
```

As others have said, static methods on a singleton is a bit naughty. Do it some other way if you can.