# Can anyone see whether my singleton class is right?

Tags: java, android, singleton

```
public class GsonUtils {

    private static class Holder {
        static final Gson INSTANCE = new Gson();
    }

    public static Gson getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

it s all;

Comment: as there is no class `Gson` shown, probably not as you initialize it from another class.

Comment: The `Holder` class is useless here. Just bring the field into `GsonUtils`.

Comment: public class GsonUtils {
    private Gson gson;

    private GsonUtils() {
        gson = new Gson();
    }

    private static class Holder {
        static final GsonUtils INSTANCE = new GsonUtils();
    }

    public static GsonUtils getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public Gson getGson() {
        return gson;
    }
}

Comment: Your singleton should have a private constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can pull the field `INSTANCE` up to class level. No need for another encapsulation that does nothing.

```
public class GsonUtils {
    private static final Gson INSTANCE = new Gson();

    private GsonUtils() {
        // you do not want someone to instantiate this
    }

    public static Gson getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

You can also lazy initialize the singleton:

```
public class GsonUtils {
    private static Gson INSTANCE;

    private GsonUtils() {
        // you do not want someone to instantiate this
    }

    public static Gson getInstance() {
        if(INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Gson();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

See [Java Singleton Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832297/java-singleton-pattern) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks for your help!!!