# Proper singleton design?

Tags: java, methods, static, singleton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficient way to implement singleton pattern in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/efficient-way-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-java)

I have a singleton class that acts as a state saver for my application. For instance if I have a view that has some data, I just pacakge the data to a saved state serializable object and pass it to my singleton for retrival later. This all seems natural and proper, but I have deviated from the singleton example on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Intead of having a get instance method that will let me retrieve the instance and call methods though the instance, I instead just set every method to static and use the class statically.

Is this bad form? Is there a performance lose?

Thanks for any tips ~Aedon

Comment: see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/efficient-way-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If static use fulfills your needs, I don't see any evil in it.

The only downside is that it's slightly less flexible. If you designed it as an actual singleton, you could have an interface for managing state, and instantiate a particular implementation for a specific situation. This object could then be passed into your application as an argument.

Using a strictly static class, there's not object to pass, so you'd have to resort to passing around Class objects and accessing the functions through that interface.

Of course, all of that only matters if there's any chance this would ever expand beyond the reasonable capabilities of your current class.

Comment: Hmmm interesting. Thank you. one of the reasons I went all static is for ease of access (which is a fancy way of saying lazy design). If I'm getting deeper into an application and I realize it's slightly cumbersome to get access to some data, I find it easier to just use the all static class.

Comment: Hmm, making it a singleton should just add one line of code to each use. i.e. instead of "foo=Single.getFoo();" you'd have "Single single=Single.getIntance(); foo=single.getFoo();". If you only need one field from the singleton, it would just make the one line slightly longer, like "foo=Single.getInstance().getFoo();" That seems a fairly small price to pay for the long-run flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is considered bad form.

Static classes in Java have a number of problems that make them difficult to work with. For example, you can't implement an interface. Also, if you ever need to make it a regular Singleton again -- or need to make it a non-Singleton, which happens quite often -- you'll have to rewrite every line of code that interacted with it.

Comment: I would argue that based on experience, the changing to non-Singleton would require refactoring every line anyway since the most common way singletons are accessed is MySingleton.getInstance().someMethod().  Not that I dispute the rest, just that particular point.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using only static methods and variables is not the object oriented way.
Singletons are mostly considered a bad practice. However, I admit they are very useful sometimes. Here is a simple example of how to create a valid and functional Singleton class. Note that there are other ways too, but this is one of the most common...

```
public class Singleton {
   private static final Singleton uniqueInstance;

   public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
     if (Singleton.uniqueInstance == null) {
       Singleton.uniqueInstance = new Singleton();
     }
     return Singleton.uniqueInstance;
   }

   //other methods go here...

   @Override
   protected Singleton clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException() {
     throw new CloneNotSupporedException("cloning of singleton is not supported");
   }

   //hide constructor for others to see
   private Singleton() {
   }
}
```

cheers, P

Comment: superfluous posting of code...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of how singleton's are done, I just was curious if the static way of doing things was less effcient.

Comment: how is that unnecessary if @AedonEtLIRA is not sure how to write a singleton and does it only with static methods?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA ok - I didn't exactly got this from your question... :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

[Use Enum instead of Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427902/java-enum-singleton). It's the safest way.

Comment: Could you please be more general? And your phrasing is all wrong.

Comment: @little bunny foo foo - agreed. @Boris - I'm not entirely sure I follow.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA, what @Boris was trying to say is that the `enum` singleton pattern is the preferred singleton implementation.

Comment: -1 This may be true, but this is a comment (about a duplicate), not a new answer.

Comment: @Little bunny foo foo - I see.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered bad form because it's not object-oriented style.  Many consider singletons poor form anyway.  Frankly, it'll work just fine for what you're trying to do.  Unless you're going to present this for review or evaluation I'd leave it alone.

Performance will likely be better as a static class.

Comment: Personally I've never been much persuaded by arguments of the "it's bad because it's not object-oriented". My reaction is, "So what?" Whenever the justification for something is, "Because all the experts say so" or "because that's what the textbook says", I take that to mean, "I don't really know why".

Answer (score 0):

Add to @Boris' comment, if all you need is a Utility class its is even simpler using an enum

```
public enum Utility {
    ; // no instances
    public static Object myStaticMethod(Object ... args) { }
}
```

If you have an interface to implement, this a singleton makes sense.  Note, you can create more than one Singleton with an enum

```
public enum Callables implements Callable<String> {
    HELLO {
         public String call() { return "Hello"; }
    }, 
    WORLD {
         public String call() { return "World"; }
    }
}
```

Note: HELLO and WORLD share a super class Callables but actually have different classes.