# NullpointerException with connection object creating SQL statement

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I am getting a nullpointerexception with this line of code

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

The servlet that uses this was working ok a few days back and I recovered from a previous version of my class from my repository and it still is not working , so I am guessing it is maybe a server side problem.

However to be sure I want to get as much information as possible , what would be the best way to debug.

I have tried using

```
 e.toString()
```

However this only gives "nullpointerexception" message.

**Stack Trace**

> > 
>
> - [24/Dec/2012:11:59:24] warning (27454): CORE3283: stderr:    java.lang.NullPointerException
> - [24/Dec/2012:11:59:24] warning (27454): CORE3283: stderr:       at    org.ari.DatabaseLogic.getData(DatabaseLogic.java:80)
> - [24/Dec/2012:11:59:24] warning (27454): CORE3283: stderr:       at    org.ari.ARIServlet.doPost(ARIServlet.java:72)
> - [24/Dec/2012:11:59:24] warning (27454): CORE3283: stderr:       at    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:807)
> - [24/Dec/2012:11:59:24] warning (27454): CORE3283: stderr:       at    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:908)
> - [24/Dec/2012:11:59:24] warning (27454): CORE3283: stderr:       at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invokeServletService(StandardWrapperValve.java:771)

**Database Logic Class**

```
    public class DatabaseLogic
{
    private static Connection conn;

    public static void openDatabase() throws IOException, SQLException,
            NamingException
    {


        // context class gives naming standards of the surrounding environment
        // of the servlet i.e. the web server ,
        // allowing the servlet to interface with the web servers resources
        Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
        // servlet looks up for a connection pool called "jdbc/POOL"
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/POOL");
        // connection is then made/requests to connection pool

        try
        {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());                   
        }
    }


    // queryId is the parameter to be used for querying for relevant records
    public static String getData(String queryId, int requestNumber)
            throws SQLException
    {
        String result = "";
        if (queryId != null)
        {
            try
            {
                // prepare a statement for use in query
                result = "This code breaks at this point";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                // query parameratised with queryId
                String qry = "SELECT RECORD_ID, USER_ID, OPERATION_CD, BUSCOMP_NAME, OPERATION_DT, FIELD_NAME, OLD_VAL, NEW_VAL, AUDIT_LOG, ROW_ID, BC_BASE_TBL FROM S_AUDIT_ITEM WHERE RECORD_ID='"
                        + queryId + "'";
                ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
                result = XMLBuilder.xmlBuilder(results, queryId,
                        requestNumber);
                // close the connection
                stmt.close();
                results.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // log.error("Cannot connect to database :" + e);


            }
        }
        else
        {
            // not sure if ever reached
            result = "The query parameter  is a null value";
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

I have a connection pool setup on my web server and it is running.

Any other ideas or recommendations?

Thanks

Merry Christmas and Happy Holidays!

Comment: Is this JNDI jdbc/POOL available, I hope program not able to find JNDI that's why you may be getting NPE

Comment: @PradeepSimha ; I have a jdbc pool and JNDI setup. Is there a way to confirm this

Comment: I think you are facing problems said by answers below. Check if that works.

Comment: It surprises me sadly very much that none of the commenters/answerers so far have spotted **severe** threadsafety and resource leaking problems in the code shown so far. This code is a disaster in a multi-user environment such as a web application. To learn more about your mistakes, start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428573/is-it-safe-to-use-a-static-connection-java-sql-object-in-a-multithreaded-syste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you calling `openDatabase` before calling `getData`?

If you aren't then `conn` is `null` and `conn.createStatement` will trigger the null pointer exception

Comment: conn = ds.getConnection();

Comment: Yes in my main class - public void init()
 {
  
  try
  {
   DatabaseLogic.openDatabase();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();  
  }

 }

Comment: Ok there seems to be a problem with openDatabase setting conn object.

Comment: I tried this and it still is null, there is something wrong with conn not being able to be set.

Comment: It turns out there was nothing wrong with my code, i had misconfigured the JDBC pool , d'oh :(

Answer (score 3):

try

if (conn == NULL) { 
 openDatabase();
}

Just ahead of your createStatement

Comment: Ok I used your code and indeed conn is NULL however my openDatabase does not seem to be setting it for some reason, could it be because its a static variable?