# Image Servlet Image returning as null

Tags: java, sql, image, oracle, servlets

Hi i have tried following this very helpful tut found here:

http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/imageservlet.html

I am following the tutorial to try and create my image servlet which retrieves an image from a database and displays it the the user on my jsp page. As far as i am aware the code looks ok, but the console is showing me a 500 internal error and my server console indicates that my Image variable is null here:

```
Image image = dataManager.getPhotos(homeId);
```

Below is my complete code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "ImageServlet", urlPatterns = {"/Image"})
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240; // 10KB.
private static DatabaseConnector dataManager;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Get ID from request.
    String homeId = request.getParameter("id");

    // Check if ID is supplied to the request.
    if (homeId == null) {
        // Do your thing if the ID is not supplied to the request.
        // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image, or just ignore it.
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
        return;
    }
    try {
        // Lookup Image by ImageId in database.
        // Do your "SELECT * FROM Image WHERE ImageID" thing.
        Image image = dataManager.getPhotos(homeId);

        // Check if image is actually retrieved from database.
        if (image == null) {
            // Do your thing if the image does not exist in database.
            // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image, or just ignore it.
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

        // Init servlet response.
        response.reset();
        response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(image.getLength()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + image.getHomeID() + "\"");

        // Prepare streams.
        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            // Open streams.
            input = new BufferedInputStream(image.getContent(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Write file contents to response.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            // Gently close streams.
            close(output);
            close(input);
        }

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImageServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImageServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImageServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private static void close(Closeable resource) {
    if (resource != null) {
        try {
            resource.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Do your thing with the exception. Print it, log it or mail it.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My Database Connector below handles and retrieves the data below:

```
 public Image getPhotos(String homeID) throws
        IllegalArgumentException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    createConnection();

    Image img = new Image();

    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    String strQuery = "SELECT * "
            + "FROM home_photo "
            + "WHERE home_photo.home_id = ?";

    try {
        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, homeID);
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            img.setHomeID(rs.getInt("home_id"));
            img.setPhotoID(rs.getInt("photo_id"));
            img.setContent(rs.getBinaryStream("photo"));
            img.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            img.setLength(rs.getInt("length"));
            img.setContentType(rs.getString("type"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new SQLException(e);
    }

    closeConnection();
    return img;
}
```

Of which i cant see where it would return img and null?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem and the code suggests that it's *actually* the `dataManager` which is `null`. The code is written in such way that if the `image` would ever be `null`, then it would just return a 404, not a 500 with a `NullPointerException`.

You need to make sure that the `dataManager` is not `null`, e.g. by instantiating it in `init()` method, or if it's an EJB, by injecting it as `@EJB`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `DatabaseConnector` being a `static` variable and the JDBC `Connection` being declared as an instance variable is also not a good sign. This code is not thread safe. Start here to learn how to write proper JDBC code: [Is it safe to use a static java.sql.Connection instance in a multithreaded system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428573/is-it-safe-to-use-a-static-java-sql-connection-instance-in-a-multithreaded-syste) On the very same blog as you found the image servlet, you can also find a basic [JDBC DAO tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. i have used an int() method to instatiante the dataManager. But the code has now fired a "Stream Closed" exception in my console at the while loop in the servlet

Comment: That's actually a different problem for which you should have asked a new question :) But ala, you need to replace `InputStream content` by `byte[] content` and use `ResultSet#getBytes()` to obtain it. It's basically caused by `InputStream` not being available anymore after closing the connection.