# Managed Bean - Only execute code on page load

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, javabeans

I'm curious about how to get JSF to only load certain business logic *on page load* and **not run this code** when I click a button (`ActionEvent`) or execute an `AjaxBehaviorEvent`.

My bean is in `@RequestScoped`, using JSF 2.1 and Primefaces.

Because the `ActionEvent` and `AjaxBehaviorEvent` are called afterwards I don't know how to tell the Bean in `@PostConstruct` that it is called because of the events.

Is it because of the bean placed in wrong scope?

Comment: Inject a ViewScoped bean which has the @PostConstruct code into your RequestScoped bean. There could be a better way. So wait...

Comment: I got serious problems with ViewScoped. It always needs a serialized class which I find anoying ;) - additionally it causes sligth problems with 'java.sql'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Only execute code on <strike>page load</strike> GET request*

Just check in (post)constructor if [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29) returns `false`.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the upcoming JSF 2.2 you can by the way use the new `<f:viewAction>` for this instead.

```html
<f:viewAction action="#{bean.init}" onPostback="false" />
```

---

> *Is it because of the bean placed in wrong scope?*

Depends on the concrete functional requirements. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)

---

> *I got serious problems with ViewScoped. It always needs a serialized class which I find anoying ;) - additionally it causes sligth problems with 'java.sql'*

This indicates a problem with your own code design rather than with the view scope. JDBC code doesn't belong in a JSF managed bean. JDBC resources like `Connection`, etc should [never, never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428573/is-it-safe-to-use-a-static-java-sql-connection-instance-in-a-multithreaded-syste) be declared as instance variables.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'll read into that however this will take some time now. Therefor I got another question now: Should I use JDBC with try-finally block inside the bean, or a separate class and call it from the bean (would this make any difference?)? Or is it better to switch to JPA or something similar?

Comment: First step would be to stop declaring JDBC resources as instance variables. That they're not serializable should already have been a sufficient hint that you did things the wrong way. What you do thereafter is up to you. Keep reusability, testability and maintainability in mind. Carefully read the linked post and all of its links.

Answer (score 1):

A RequestScoped bean is re-created on each request sent from client to server, that's why the logic in @PostConstruct is executed everytime  you click a button, i think you should use a ViewScoped bean instead, which is created on each page load.

You can find a good tutorial about this subject written by BalusC on this link: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes