# java.io.NotSerializableException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection

Tags: jsf, serialization, jdbc

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server with JSF.

I've been receiving this exception:

```
IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1587)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5169)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1663)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1077)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.call(StandardContext.java:5391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.call(StandardContext.java:5374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've set the Java Bean related to the SQL Server as `implements Serializable`, for example

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SqlBean implements Serializable {

    private Connection  conn = null;

    public SqlBean() {
        super();
        System.out.println("Starts to read!");
        String dbName = "//some dbName";
        String serverip="//some serverip";
        String serverport="//some serverport";
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverip+"\\SQLEXPRESS:"+serverport+";databaseName="+dbName+"";
        String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
        String databaseUserName = "//some user";
        String databasePassword = "//some password";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, databaseUserName, databasePassword);
            if(conn!=null) System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error Trace in getConnection() : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The connection is always successful. Totally lost on this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very wrong in 2 ways:

```
//resource injection
private Connection  conn = null;
```

1. This is definitely not resource injection.
2. Keeping a connection open that long and sharing it across multiple requests in a HTTP session is bad design and not threadsafe.

You should rewrite all your JDBC code in such way that you acquire and close all DB resources `Connection`, `(Prepared)Statement` and `ResultSet` in the shortest possible scope in the very same try-finally block.

Your concrete problem is caused because a DB connection does not implement `Serializable` for the very simple reason that a TCP/IP connection *can't* be serializable.

#### See also:

- [Is it safe to use a static java.sql.Connection instance in a multithreaded system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428573/is-it-safe-to-use-a-static-java-sql-connection-instance-in-a-multithreaded-syste/9431863#9431863) (much similar to your design problem)

---

Please note that this problem is completely unrelated to JSF. You should put all that JDBC code in [standalone DAO classes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) and make sure that all your JSF managed beans are completely free of `java.sql` imports. To get a step further, start learning EJB and JPA. This way all the DB interaction can be done in oneliners without any need for all the raw connection/statement/resultset mess. That's also the path you're supposed to follow if you want to go Java EE.

Comment: Is using transient a bad practice?

Comment: Depends on whether it's been used as a solution or a workaround. If as a workaround, then it's definitely bad. My answer describes the solution. If you'd use `transient` instead of applying my answer, then it'd be a workaround. You're merely postponing/moving/hiding the real problem instead of really fixing it.

Comment: Why is it bad? I'm using it as a workaround

Comment: Because the problem as described in my answer still persists.