# Close DB connection on browser close

Tags: java, jsf

I use Primefaces / JSF2. Due to a special case we use jdbc connection instead of connection pool. Every logged in user will hold one and only DB connection at a time. If a logged in user close the browser instead of a proper logout, his DB connection get held till the idle timeout (15 mins) and he cannot login again immediately within this 15 mins timeout.

Is there any way to close the user DB connection, if he closes the browser instead of logout?

Comment: You can create a jdbc session per browser request instead of per browser session. That way you are always closing it when each request finishes.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way. At least, no reliable way. You could perhaps set the session timeout to 1 minute, keep it alive with ajax polling and use `HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed()` to close the connection. But still, the whole approach is very brittle and prone to failure.

You should **always** acquire and close the DB resources in the shortest possible scope within the very same `try-finally` block as where the SQL query/queries are fired, no excuses. A Java EE web application is really not comparable to a plain Java desktop application where the enduser can just restart the buggy application itself if it crashes due to DB resource leaking.

#### See also:

- [Is it safe to use a static java.sql.Connection instance in a multithreaded system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428573/is-it-safe-to-use-a-static-java-sql-connection-instance-in-a-multithreaded-syste/9431863#9431863) — whilst not exactly the same problem/question as yours, the answer is very applicable in your case.