# Does accessing the RequestContext from ApplicationScoped bean need synchronization?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two questions:

1. Is it legal to access the `RequestContext` from PrimeFaces inside an `@ApplicationScoped` bean?
2. Must the access to the `RequestContext` be synchronized?

**Backing bean**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyDatabaseConnection
{
  public void do()
  {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    // ...
  }
}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{myDatabaseConnection.do}"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is it legal to access the RequestContext from PrimeFaces inside an @ApplicationScoped bean?*

Yes, as long as you don't assign it as an instance variable (property) of the application scoped bean.

Note that the same holds true for `FacesContext`, `ExternalContext`, `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`, `HttpSesison`, etc..etc.. They are all not application scoped and can thus cause major trouble when being assigned/shared as a property of an application scoped bean.

I must admit that your chosen bean class name `MyDatabaseConnection` really scares me in combination with `@ApplicationScoped` annotation. A database connection absolutely isn't intented to be application scoped. See also among others: [Is it safe to use a static java.sql.Connection instance in a multithreaded system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428573/is-it-safe-to-use-a-static-java-sql-connection-instance-in-a-multithreaded-syste/9431863#9431863)

---

> *Must the access to the RequestContext be synchronized?*

No, you don't need to. It's in the current code example been obtained in the method local scope and not assigned as a property of the bean.

The following answers should be helpful in understanding the meaning of "request", "session" and "application" scopes:

- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)