# Initializing static fields in the constructor

Tags: java, static, variable-assignment

If I have a static field that I want to initialize, will initializing it in the constructor cause it to be assigned every time a new instance of the class is instantiated?

```
    private static Connection connection;

    public Database() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    } catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I could do this:

```
    private static Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

However I need to have exception handling. I have also looked at using a static block to but this has caused problems.

Comment: `but this has caused problems.` ???

Comment: Just don't use `static` members/initializers. Do everything with objects.

Comment: No, I'm just thinking in terms of efficiency. I don't want to be instantiating a new connection object and assigning it for every instance.

Comment: If you want it, ``static`` initializer or a static method (better imho, because you can name your method) is the way to go. What's the problem?

Comment: Can't you create a connection object and pass that to every class that needs it using DI? No need for `static` and much easier to test.

Comment: When I use a static initializer the next instance I instantiate doesn't work properly. Sorry to be vague, just that I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: What does "doesn't work properly" mean?  Use a debugger to find out what happens.

Comment: A static initializer is only executed once. You have not shown code that describes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will initializing it in the constructor cause it to be assigned every time a new instance of the class is instantiated?

Yes; code in the constructor will run whenever you construct an object.

You need to use a static initializer block.

Answer (score 1):

Static fields are belong to class, not to any instance of that class. So, initializing it in the constructor doesn't make any sense. Since for every instance creation, that will be reinitialized. This may cause problems to you. Use static initializer to initialize them and have class loading time initializer for static fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a static constructor to initialize static variables that need more initialization than just a simple assignment. Of course you can only use static variables in a static constructor. For your example:

```
class Database {
    private static Connection connection;

    static {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        } catch (...) {}
    }

    ...
}
```

In this example, HOST, USERNAME and PASSWORD need to be static variables too (in this class or somewhere else is fine). However, I doubt you really want to initialize your database like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how static fields work. They are shared across all instances of your class; any time you call `new Database()`, it'll reset the connection.

For databases, you should use connection pooling instead of a single, shared connection.

What you want is a static initializer:

```
static {
    try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        } catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This block executes the first time you touch the static field (which will be when you create a new `Database` instance).

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to use a static Connection object across multiple instances.
[Related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428573/is-it-safe-to-use-a-static-java-sql-connection-instance-in-a-multithreaded-syste)