# if(rs.next()) block placed after while(rs.next()) is never entered

Tags: java, if-statement, jdbc

In below snippet, the `else` is always invoked. The `if` is never entered, even though the `while` block is successfully entered.

```
while (rs.next()) {

     username = rs.getString(2);
     password = rs.getString(3);

}
if(rs.next())
{
   response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp");

}        
else {
  response.sendRedirect("Fail.jsp");
}
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I put right username and password and i got redirected to fail.jsp instead of welcome.jsp

Comment: This is dangerous code. You open a connection in the `init()` method and never close it. Connections are typically obtained and returned within a request/response

Comment: Yes it is , how to close it ? I thin it would be better if i create a DBConnection java class instead of putting it with the servlet class

Comment: Please learn how to ask focused questions. This is again not a JSP/Servlet related problem. I clarified the question. As to the dangerously threadunsafe JDBC connection management in your initial snippet, head to http://stackoverflow.com/q/9428573 (and in the meanwhile also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106452)

Comment: You loop until `rs.next()` returns false and thus should return false in the if-condition as well, why should it enter the block then? I guess what you actually want is to check whether the loop executed at least once, e.g. by checking `username != null`.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry , thanks for feeding back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you possibly wanted:

```
if(rs.next()) {
    username = rs.getString(2);
    password = rs.getString(3);
    response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp");
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("Fail.jsp");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation of `next()` method of resultset [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()).

> When a call to the `next` method returns false, the cursor is
>   positioned after the last row.

So, when control comes out of while loop, cursor has already reached the position after the last row and hence, `rs.next()` will never return true. I wold like to suggest a couple of changes:

- Add a flag in the while loop which is set to true of control enters inside while loop and then check for that flag, e.g.:

  `boolean exists = false;
      while(rs.next(){
       exists = true;
       //other logic
      }
      if(exists){
       response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp");
      }`
- Add proper [exception handling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-exceptions.htm) in the code.