# Using Singleton DB Connection ( to connect to SAS) in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, sas

I'm using a singleton static connection (this is not JDBC) to connect my Java web application to a SAS server. According to my understanding Tomcat creates thread safe objects of each concurrent request hands them over to threads from a thread pool to fulfil. My question is how will my DB connection behave in this setup? Since this is a non-JDBC connection, Tomcat does not have a DB connection pool to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a singleton class to handle your DB connection, then it will be thread safe by it's nature. 
Tomcat offers a thread safe implementation for the web application requests. In your implementation, Tomcat threads will use your singleton class for communicating with the DB.

I would also recommend to read more about managing DB connection pools using singleton:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126621/simple-singleton-database-connection-pool
http://rdeshapriya.com/a-singleton-java-class-for-mysql-db-connection/
[If I use a singleton class for a database connection, can one user close the connection for everybody?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567839/if-i-use-a-singleton-class-for-a-database-connection-can-one-user-close-the-con)