# How to create a global "C#" class

Tags: c#, sql, database

How to create a global "C#" class for data base connection such that:
1. all classes and controls can handle.
2. remian all session untill the main from of an application closed.
3. disconnect from the server when closing windows Form application

Comment: You can use singleton or database pool as described in this topic:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507687/should-a-db-connection-be-a-singleton)

Comment: "remain all sessions" is a very bad idea, almost a system killer! And there's no such thing as "global" in OOP, the nearest thing are static classes (but not necessarily the best choice for what you intend).

Comment: Thomas' points are well-taken... and **very well answered at yursol's link**... where the first answer is very helpful, re' database connection pools.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **[Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)** Design pattern. A Singleton ensures there is a global access point to a class and that there is only one instance of the class. It is far superior to a static class. [Singleton vs. Static Class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)

### Singleton

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance;

    // Private Constructor.
    private Singleton()
    {
        // This ensures no other class but this can create instances of the Singleton.
    }

    // Returns the instance of this class.
    public static Singleton getInstance()
    {
        // Check if an instance of this class already exists.
        if(instance == null)
           // It doesn't exist so create it. 
           instance = new Singleton();

        // Return the instance.
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is a Singleton 'far superior'? After all, it basically _is_ a static class. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I will post a link just for you (This has been covered extensively, I wanted OP to research). I will give you a very practical example though. What if you want to change your class from static to non-static, how many functions will you have to edit-out the `static` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using *Singleton design pattern*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Typical *thread-safe* implementation can be like this:

```
public sealed class Program {
  private static Object s_SyncObj = new Object();

  private static volatile Program s_Instance;

  private Program() {
    ...    
  }

  public static Program Instance {
    get {
      if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, s_Instance)) 
        return s_Instance;

      lock (s_SyncObj) {
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, s_Instance)) 
          return s_Instance;

        s_Instance = new Program(); 
      }

      return s_Instance; 
    }
  }
}
```

You can also try using just a *static class*:

```
public static class Program {
  ...
}
```