# Cache JDBC connections

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I have a small e-commerce application which relies heavliy on the database. I've seen some performance issues with it, primary when it comes to establishing a connection to the database. I'm not a DBA, or any other deep DB knowledge - but I know that it makes sense to cache the connections instead of establishing a new one all the time.

Below is my method for getting the connection:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException  {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://182.31.456.32:3306/"+database+"",""+username+"",""+password+""); 
   // stm=con.createStatement(); 
    return con;
}
```

My question is - how can I easily cache a current connection and reuse it instead of creating a new one using JDBC/Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In a situation where you have a **pretty large e-commerce application**, you don't usually code DB connection they way you show in your code.

We make use of connection pools.

I guess, your e-commerce application would be deployed in some application server, use connection pool facility of that server to manage your database connections.

You can use one of connection pool APIs like C3P0 etc to explicitly code pooling functionality if its an application without a server.

I guess the thing that you are calling a connection caching is basically to ask to implement a **Singleton**. There would be lots of examples on Internet as how to implement a singleton but you shouldn't be closing connections in code then.

There is something called **connection-timeout** time, you need to set that properly if going with single connection caching solution.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks a lot , this is something new to me :)

Comment: I think people aren't upvoting enough around here, so I do my part to change that ;-)

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a **connection pool** that you can easily configure out of the box in `Tomcat`, this way the connection pool will be managed directly by `Tomcat` which avoids a lot of integration issues, guarantees a full compatibility and avoids adding new dependencies.

Here are the steps to follow:

#### 1. Define the connection pool globally

In `conf/contex.xml` you need to define your connection pool as `Resource` so for example in you case it could be something like that:

```
<Context>

    ...
    <Resource name="jdbc/myPool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                initialSize="5" maxActive="20" minIdle="5" maxIdle="15" maxWait="10000"
                validationQuery="SELECT 1" validationQueryTimeout="5"
                testWhileIdle="true" testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="false"
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000" minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
                removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="300" logAbandoned="false"
                poolPreparedStatements="true"
                username="myUsername" password="myPassword"
                driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
                url="jdbc:mysql://182.31.456.32:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true" />
</Context>
```

#### 2. Declare your connection pool for your webapp

In the `web.xml` of your webapp, you need to define it locally using a `resource-ref` as next:

```
<web-app>
    ...
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/myPool</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
    ...
</web-app>
```

#### 3. Access to my datasource from my code

You can then access to your [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) using [JNDI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi/index.html)

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/myPool");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

#### 4. Deploy your `JDBC` driver

Your `JDBC` driver needs to be available in the [**Common ClassLoader**](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) of Tomcat as it is a global resource, such that you need to put the jar of your driver in `tomcat/lib`

---

More details about `JNDI` Datasource in `Tomcat` [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

Answer (score -1):

You could use a singleton class like the one below:

```
public class DBHandler{

    private static Connection conn = null;

    private DBHandler(String connString){
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connString);    
    }

    public static void getConnection(String connString) {
        if (conn == null)
            new DBHandler(String connString);
        return conn;
    }
}
```

It will create the connection during the first `DBHandler.getConnection()`call and caches it in the `conn` field. Later `DBHandler.getConnection()` calls will return this cached connection.

If your application needs to handle a lot of DB requests,please read about Connection Pooling as well.

Comment: This is really bad advice. For large scale applications you don't use a singleton connection: you use a connection pool.

Comment: I understand that and I had pointed that in my answer.  I was actually replying to his question `how can I easily cache a current connection and reuse it instead of creating a new one using JDBC/Java?`
Also the question was tagged `tomcat`. I had never seen large e-commerce sites running on tomcat. So I assumed he is kind of starting from scratch and is looking for basic info

Comment: Doing what you show in your answer might only make sense in a single-user application, not in applications where concurrent access is possible.

Comment: Your comments on thread safety made me look into more details and got some insight from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507687/should-a-db-connection-be-a-singleton ..Thank you for that