# .NET how to prevent calling a method returning a string multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, string, constants

I'm trying to build a string of a SQL query upon initialization of a Repository class.

The repository resembles this:

```cs
public class SomeRepository<T>
{
    private readonly string _sql;

    public SomeRepository() 
    {
        _sql = GetSql();
    }

    private string GetSql()
    {
        // Build SQL string based on type T.
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Read()
    {
        // Get data with the sql string
    }
}
```

Every time I call `Read()`, the _sql string is rebuilt, even though it will never change. How can I prevent this?

I have tried making it a constant but then it must be declared in a static way which would not work with the generic typing of `T`, which is dependant on the instance of the repository.

The repository is injected with a transient scope.

Comment: Check if `_sql` is `null` (this will be the initial value of it). If so - create the string, otherwise just use it (assuming _"it will never change"_).

Comment: As above, but also you can make it `static` so the same string is shared by all instances of `SomeRepository<T>`, rather than each instance having a copy of the same string.

Comment: To further elaborate on @wohqlstad comment. Property lite this saves a null check.

    private string SqlString => _sql ??= GetSql();
    public IEnumerable<T> Read() 
    {
       // Use SqlString here
    }

Comment: It's readonly, how could it be rebuilt every time? Unless you did something wrong that you haven't told.

Comment: _"Every time I call Read(), the _sql string is rebuilt"_ **if** it is, then you are creating a new repository instance every time. So maybe take a step back and have another look.

Comment: I tried @wohlstad / atomicicebreaker 's solution, but that doesn't get me any further. I also checked Fildor 's suggestion that perhaps the repository is being created every time. This would make no sense I think, the repository is being injected as a transient. 

I'm checking the calls by setting a breakpoint on the GetSql method, then calling the read method twice. It always does. I don't understand, maybe I'm checking it wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it's hard to tell what's actually happening. (The minimal example shouldn't need an *actual* database - just fake out the database access, replacing it with hard-coded data)

Comment: "This would make no sense I think, the repository is being injected as a transient." Nope, that's what *would* make sense. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#transient) I suspect you actually want it to be injected as a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition a readonly field can only be set in the constructor so it is certain that a new instance of the repository is being created every time you see the value being set.

I am reasonably sure that you need to change its lifetime in your DI configuration. You said you are injecting it with Transient scope. That means that every repository object you pass will be different. It seems very likely that what is happening here is that you have a repository injected and used in more than one place. It is also possible that you making multiple requests and expecting it to be initialized once, in which case you would want to use  Singleton for its scope.

Here is a very clear and concise description of the differences:

> Transient objects are always different; a new instance is provided to
> every controller and every service.
>
> Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across
> different requests.
>
> Singleton objects are the same for every object and every request.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38139500/1658168

Comment: To add to this, since the OP is returning a `IEnumerable<T>` and they can only be read once. It would probably make sense to change it to a `List<T>` if there is any chance it could be iterated over twice.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I am aware of this risk, but there is no chance it will be iterated over twice.

Comment: @Peter Dongan this fixed my issues. Thanks to all. My understanding of transient/scoped/singleton was somewhat incorrect. I have one question still: does it matter that my IDbConnection is now also injected as a singleton? Does this have an impact on performance or capacity?

Comment: It might. It's discussed here (in the context of Java, but the concepts are the same): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507687/should-a-db-connection-be-a-singleton. The simplest thing would be to used scoped lifetimes for them unless the overhead of building the string is an issue. If it is an issue then you could extract the string builder into its own class and make just that new class a singleton.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at extracting the string builder into its own class. I think what you mean is that it would store the string for each type of T to ensure it does not rebuild the string every time?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.