# @Singleton or getSingletons() while implementing Singleton Resources in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I have a resource to be exposed as Restful WS.If I have to make it Singleton, what is the preferred and advised way:

1 . Annotating the resource class using `@Singleton`

Or

2 . Implementing the `getSingletons()` method in my Application class implementation and instantiating the resource there like

```
   public class RestApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public RestApplication() {
        singletons.add(new PlayerResource());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

I tried both ways and realised that both of them creates a singleton instance of the resource class, PlayerResource in this case.

Comment: A similar question on Singletons was asked here as to the best implementation. Personally I would explicitly code the singleton pattern than use an annotation. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427902/java-enum-singleton

Comment: @AdamJMTech - my question is specific to Jersey/JAX-RS. Just wanted to know which on of them is the preferred way. Or what advantage either of them brings in.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, Everything technical you need to know has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914130/when-to-use-singleton-annotation-of-jersey).

For the rest of your answer, It doesn't really matter, as long as you are consistent throughout the code base.

The advantage of not using the annotation, is that if a module not provisioned by Jersey needs the resources, it will get the same singleton. (Like if you expect any third party plug-ins to interact with this resource)

The advantage to using the annotation is that you can let Jersey take care of the annoying/tedious stuff for you. (Like resource clean-up, if you use any close-able resources.)