# When to use @Singleton annotation of Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am developing a RESTful Web Service and while reading the Jersey [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1851) I came across an annotation `@Singleton`

In my web service I am mostly returning data based on the unique keys provided as parameter.
An analogy would be return all the information of a Student when the Student_Id is passed.

So my question is when `@Singleton` would be suited in such kind of Web Services?

As per documentation for `@RequestScoped`

> If the resource is used more than one time in the request processing, always the same instance will be used.

Then in that case we should not bother to use `@Singleton` right?

Also what could be the use cases where we have to make a new instance for every request?

I did have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749378/when-to-use-singleton-in-a-jersey-resource) post but my question was not answered.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default Jersey creates a new instance of the resource class for every request. So if you don't annotate the Jersey resource class, it implicitly uses `@RequestScoped` scope. It is stated in [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1851):

> Default lifecycle (applied when no annotation is present). In this
>   scope the resource instance is created for each new request and used
>   for processing of this request. If the resource is used more than one
>   time in the request processing, always the same instance will be used.
>   This can happen when a resource is a sub resource is returned more
>   times during the matching. In this situation only on instance will
>   server the requests.

Most cases you use this default setting so you don't use `@Singleton` scope. You can also create a singleton Jersey resource class by using `@Singleton` annotation. Then you need to register the singleton class in the `MyApplication` class, e.g.,

```
@Path("/resource")
@Singleton
public class JerseySingletonClass {
    //methods ...
}

public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    /*Register JAX-RS application components.*/
    public MyApplication () {
        register(JerseySingletonClass.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Singleton did the job :) +1

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. When to use @Singleton, any use case?

Comment: I am curious about how is it going to handle concurrent requests. Will multiple threads be forked if another requests comes before first is served. If yes, then is concurrency to be handled manually?

Answer (score 2):

Came along this question, because for the first time I had a use case for **not using** @Singleton annotation.

Singleton is a design pattern, you should use it if:

- The object you are "singletonizing" keeps a state that *must be shared* and kept unique (example: a global counter)
- Generally, I design REST API without keeping a state, everything is handled in the method (full closure): so generally *all* my resources are singletons (use case: better performance)

That said, today I found this use case for not using Singleton:

```
@Path("/someendpoint/{pathparam}/somethingelse/")
//@Singleton
public class MyResource {
    @PathParam("pathparam")
    private String pathparam;
}
```

Using this, I'm bounding the path param to my instance, so it **must** be RequestScoped.
Generally, I'd have put @PathParam annotation in every method, so @Singleton would have been right on the class.

I'm not sure about the performances however, creating and destroying an object isn't a free operation

Answer (score 1):

In most cases default scope `@RequestScoped` should be sufficient for your needs.

`@Singleton` may hold state. I had the problem when my endpoint was annotated as `@Singleton` so it reused the same `EntityManager` during concurrent calls. After removing `@Singleton`, during concurrent calls, different `EntityManager` object instances are used. If endpoint calls are subsequent, it may be that previous/old `EntityManager` will be used. - [Jersey, Guice and Hibernate - EntityManager thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857481/jersey-guice-and-hibernate-entitymanager-thread-safety/38745775#38745775)

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a use case specified in the Jersey 2 manual for using the [SseBroadcaster](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.27/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/sse/SseBroadcaster.html) when serving Server-Sent events, [it is covered in this provided example](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e11432)

> The BroadcasterResource resource class is annotated with @Singleton annotation which tells Jersey runtime that only a single instance of the resource class should be used to serve all the incoming requests to /broadcast path. This is needed as we want to keep an application-wide single reference to the private broadcaster field so that we can use the same instance for all requests. Clients that want to listen to SSE events first send a GET request to the BroadcasterResource, that is handled by the listenToBroadcast() resource method.

Using the `@Singleton`, The application will only contain one `SseBroadcaster` for all incoming requests, one such broadcaster is enough to serve multiple clients, so it only needs to be instantiated once!

> JAX-RS SSE API defines SseBroadcaster which allows to broadcast individual events to multiple clients.