# REST endpoint - Singleton vs RequestScoped

Tags: java, rest, jersey, singleton, jax-rs

[When to use @Singleton annotation of Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914130/when-to-use-singleton-annotation-of-jersey) -

> By default Jersey creates a new instance of the resource class for
>   every request. So if you don't annotate the Jersey resource class, it
>   implicitly uses `@RequestScoped` scope.

`@RequestScoped` endpoint looks more suitable for various reasons. It is stateless, provides new instance for each request. I have implemented DAO's based on http://www.benmccann.com/hibernate-with-jpa-annotations-and-guice example so provided `EntityManager` objects are different only in `@RequestScoped` environment because they are received from `ThreadLocal<EntityManager>` cache ([Jersey, Guice and Hibernate - EntityManager thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857481/jersey-guice-and-hibernate-entitymanager-thread-safety)).

On the other hand, I have faced applications where Jersey endpoints are annotated as `@Singleton`. But it seems that removing annotation won't change application behavior/logic.

When `@Singleton` should be used instead of default `@RequestScoped` for REST endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter in REST-application much - unless you have a session based rest api (Hint: Don't do that, that's not the point of REST).

Singleton can get slow (in Jersey) as jersey uses a single class loader and when your API is busy replying to someone else, then all other requests to that endpoint could take a while until the former is finished.