# How to make thread safe singleton class which can accepts parameter?

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am trying to make a class as `ThreadSafe Singleton` but somehow I am not able to understand how to make `ThreadSafe Singleton` class which can accepts parameter.

Below is the class which I am using from this github [link](https://gist.github.com/definitelyMVP/4984723) which I am using currently to make a connection to Zookeeper -

```
public class LeaderLatchExample {

    private CuratorFramework client;
    private String latchPath;
    private String id;
    private LeaderLatch leaderLatch;

    public LeaderLatchExample(String connString, String latchPath, String id) {
        client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(connString, new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        this.id = id;
        this.latchPath = latchPath;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        client.start();
        client.getZookeeperClient().blockUntilConnectedOrTimedOut();
        leaderLatch = new LeaderLatch(client, latchPath, id);
        leaderLatch.start();
    }

    public boolean isLeader() {
        return leaderLatch.hasLeadership();
    }

    public Participant currentLeader() throws Exception {
        return leaderLatch.getLeader();
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        leaderLatch.close();
        client.close();
    }

    public CuratorFramework getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public String getLatchPath() {
        return latchPath;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public LeaderLatch getLeaderLatch() {
        return leaderLatch;
    }
}
```

And this is the way I am calling the above class -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String latchPath = "/latch";
        String connStr = "10.12.136.235:2181";
        LeaderLatchExample node1 = new LeaderLatchExample(connStr, latchPath, "node-1"); // this I will be doing only one time at just the initialization time
        node1.start();

        System.out.println("now node-1 think the leader is " + node1.currentLeader());
}
```

Now what I need is if I am calling these two below methods from any class in my program, I should be able to get an instance of it. So I am thinking to make above class as a Thread Safe Singleton so that I can access these two methods across all my java program.

```
isLeader()
getClient()
```

How do I make above class as ThreadSafe singleton and then make use of `isLeader()` and `getClient()` across all my classes to see who is the leader and get the client instance..

I need to do this only at the initialization time and once it is done, I should be able to use `isLeader()` and `getClient()` across all my classes.. Is this possible to do?

```
// this line I will be doing only one time at just the initialization time
LeaderLatchExample node1 = new LeaderLatchExample(connStr, latchPath, "node-1");
node1.start();
```

This is more of Java question not Zookeeper stuff..

Comment: Is there anything you need besides the patterns listed at http://stackoverflow.com/q/7048198/2636001 ?

Answer (score 3):

A singleton which requires a parameter is a bit of a contradiction in terms. After all, you'd need to supply the parameter value on every call, and then consider what would happen if the value was different to an earlier one.

I would encourage you to avoid using the singleton pattern at all here. Instead, make your class a perfectly normal one - but use dependency injection to provide a reference to a single configured instance to all your classes that need it.

That way:

- The singleton nature isn't enforced, it's just a natural part of you only *needing* one reference. If later on you needed two references (e.g. for different Zookeeper instances for some reason) you can just configure the dependency injection differently
- The lack of global state generally makes things much easier to test. One test might use one configuration; another test might use a different one. No singleton, no problem. Just pass the relevant reference into the constructor of the class under test.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I might supply parameter only at initialization time, and after that I don't want to specify any parameter and just want to use  `isLeader()` and `getClient()` method in all the classes.

Comment: In that scenario, I should also use DI to pass around?

Comment: @AKIWEB: Yes, that's what I'd do. You *could* make two static methods, one to initialize the singleton and one to fetch it, but I really wouldn't.