# Java Abstract Factories and Singletons

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, factory-pattern

I would like to implement an example of abstract factory, however concrete factories must be served as singletons.

Giving the example of Mr. Banas here : http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/09/abstract-factory-design-pattern/ I should modify UFOEnemyShipFactory and UFOBossEnemyShipFactory right ?

I tried something for UFOEnemyShipFactory but I'm not sure to be right :

```
public class UFOEnemyShipFactory implements EnemyShipFactory{

    private UFOEnemyShipFactory(){};

    private static UFOEnemyShipFactory firstInstance = null;

    public static UFOEnemyShipFactory getInstance(){
    
        if(firstInstance == null){
        
            synchronized(UFOEnemyShipFactory.class){
            
                if(firstInstance == null){
                
                    firstInstance = new UFOEnemyShipFactory();
                
                }
            
            }
        
        }
    
        return firstInstance;
    
    }

    public ESWeapon addESGun(){
        return new ESUFOGun();
    }

    public ESEngine addESEingine() {
        return new ESUFOEngine();
    }
```

It seems a bit weird, I think that I'm not applying the needed modification in the correct class. If I'm totally wrong could you please give me a brief explanation (why am I wrong and which class(es) I have to modify and why ?)

Thanks In advance.

Comment: if you really want a singleton, why not use an `enum`? The Java language does all the heavy lifting. Of course there's a lot of controversy over whether singletons are good. http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/691.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I do not have complete info on your AbstractFactory question, but I can help you on your singleton issues...

Usually when you attempt the singleton design pattern you specify a **private** constructor so others cannot use the default constructor to create their own instances.

As an additional observation, you have dropped right into the classic "double-check" anti-pattern (something to not do).  I wrote more on that here: [What's wrong with the following getInstance() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835985/whats-wrong-with-the-following-getinstance-method/26836193#26836193)
Basically, don't check outside of a sync block, synchronize, then check again.  It looks like it is safe, but it is not.  For this:

```
public static UFOEnemyShipFactory getInstance(){
    if(firstInstance == null){
        synchronized(UFOEnemyShipFactory.class){
            if(firstInstance == null){
                firstInstance = new UFOEnemyShipFactory();
            }
        }
    }
    return firstInstance;
}
```

write either this:

```
public static synchronized UFOEnemyShipFactory getInstance(){
    if(firstInstance == null){
                firstInstance = new UFOEnemyShipFactory();
    }
    return firstInstance;
}
```

or many would argue better:

```
private static final UFOEnemyShipFactory firstInstance = new UFOEnemyShipFactory();

public static UFOEnemyShipFactory getInstance(){
    return firstInstance;
}
```

Also a style point.  While in theory you can name things like you wish, "firstInstance" begs questions.  Is there a "secondInstance"?  But, "instance" (at least in the java sense) normally means "the one and only".  Better just "instance".  If your idea is to have 2 singletons hanging around somewhere, but they are distinct, you might name them, `ufoBossInstance` and `ufoGruntInstance`, for example following the naming of the references page.

Comment: Your second code post is pointless; you can just make it a single null check. The reason to double-check for null (at least in theory) is that you can do one of the checks cheaply before synchronizing.

Comment: @Jason S. Yep, thanks. Edit mistake on my part...corrected.