# How to initialize Java enum based Singleton?

Tags: java, enums, singleton

What is the proper way to initialize java enum based singleton, if I have to initialize it before I can use the object.

I have started writing the code , but I am not sure if I am doing it right. Could you help me to implement this singleton correct for me?

```
public enum BitCheck {

    INSTANCE;

    private static HashMap<String, String> props = null;

    public synchronized void  initialize(HashMap<String, String> properties) {
        if(props == null) {
            props = properties;
        }
    }

    public boolean isAenabled(){
        return "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(props.get("A_ENABLED"));
    }

    public boolean isBenabled(){
        return "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(props.get("B_ENABLED"));
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't like this, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you need an enum with only one element when you are already using a singleton?

Comment: @Dunes I want a singleton so that I can use this throughout my code base to check values. I will initialize with the properties during startup and will use the check methods all over the project.

Comment: I understand why you might want a singleton, but to also make it an enum seems bizarre.

Comment: @Dunes Thanks. I understand. What you are saying is , I should implement a regular singleton instead of using "Enum"??

Comment: Pretty much. Enums and Singletons are pretty much the antithesis of each other. Enums are designed to have multiple elements. For instance, they implement the Comparable interface and there is a specialised `Set` and `Map` class just for enums -- things you have absolutely no need for with a singleton.

Comment: @Dunes Please read this SO question for some enlightenment regarding using Enums as Singletons: [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to create constructor for `enum`:

```
public enum BitCheck {

    INSTANCE;

    BitCheck() {
        props = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    private final Map<String, String> props;

    //..

}
```

Note that:

- `props` field can be final (we like `final`)
- `props` doesn't have to be `static`
- constructor is called automatically and eagerly for you

Pay attention to the last point. Since `enum`-singletons are created eagerly when the `enum BitCheck` class is loaded, you have no way to pass any arguments to the constructor. Of course you can through `INSTANCE` declaration:

```
public enum BitCheck {

    INSTANCE(new HashMap<String, String>());

    BitCheck(final Map<String, String> props) {
        this.props = props;
    }
```

but this doesn't make any difference, right? What do you want to achieve? Maybe you actually need lazy-initialized singleton?

Comment: I guess It will be bad Idea to create like this since constructor does not offer anything good. It can be simple declaration

Comment: I want to initialize with a set of values, that I want to pass it to the singleton. How can I do that? Your example is initializing with empty hashmap.

Comment: @java_mouse: that's the thing. There is no way to pass anything to the constructor from outside, `enum` singleton won't help you.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Thanks, I think I got it. I should go for traditional singleton implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You have to just initialize it in declaration.

```
public enum BitCheck {
    INSTANCE;
    private final Map<String, String> props = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    public void putAll(HashMap<String, String> map) {
        props.putAll(map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a constructor like this:

```
public enum BitCheck {

    INSTANCE;
    private final HashMap<String, String> props;

    BitCheck() {

    }
}
```

A very good example is the Planet enum at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum BitCheck {

    INSTANCE;

    private BitCheck() {
        // initialize here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement to interfaces and therefore change to:

```
private Map<...> props;
```

You can look at [What is the best approach for using an Enum as a singleton in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427902/what-is-the-best-approach-for-using-an-enum-as-a-singleton-in-java) which is similar to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this within your Enum based singleton code. This will make sure that the Singleton can be initialized exactly once.

```
private static Properties props;
private static AtomicBoolean isInitialized = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public void init(Properties props){
   if(isInitialized.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
       this.props = props;
   }
}
```

NOTE: For more complex initialization, you would need 2 AtomicBooleans for initStarted and initCompleted (instead of single AtomicBoolean - isInitialized). Then the first thread sets initStarted and executes the initialization steps, the rest wait until initCompleted is set to true by first thread.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by complex initialization and why would we need 2 atomic booleans. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think your above code should work fine as long as I have all the initialization code (however many steps) within that 'if' block.