# Initializing StringBuffer with new operator inside a static method . is the stringbuffer reference thread safe?

Tags: java, static

Does creating a StringBuffer testing= null;

```
testing = new StringBuffer("Thread Safe ");
```

inside a static method . Does the same reference of stringbuffer gets modified by thread every time in case multiple threads are calling the function at the same time.

```
public static StringBuffer test(String string) {       
    StringBuffer testing = null;
    testing = new StringBuffer("Thread Safe ");
    return testing;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Threadsafe static initialization of ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009918/threadsafe-static-initialization-of-executorservice)

Comment: If it's a local variable within the method, then each caller (and thus thread) will get their own object.