# Hashmap updates not reflected between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

I have a singleton class that contains a hahsmap, the hashmap is initialised as a class variable. This map is updated correctly because when i add and print the size it changed, but, when i call it from a different thread the map is always empty. Is there a particular reason why this might happen?

I am using a ConccurentHashMap if this makes any difference.

Thanks

```
Singleton decleration:

    public class ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton {

        private static ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton instance = null;
        private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> tickerToNumberRegistered = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer>();


        protected ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton() {
             // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
        }

        public static ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton getInstance() {
            if(instance == null) {
               instance = new ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public void setTickerToNumberRegistered(ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> tickerToNumberRegistered) {
            this.tickerToNumberRegistered = tickerToNumberRegistered;
        }

        public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> getTickerToNumberRegistered() {
            return tickerToNumberRegistered;
        }


    public void addToClienets(String ticker){}

    public void removeFromClients(String ticker){}
}
```

Calling it from another thread:

```
String[] splitForTicker = message.split(",");

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton.getInstance().getTickerToNumberRegistered();
        System.out.println("The number of items in the map from senders persepctive" + map.size());
```

Output:

> ```
> The number of items in the map from senders persepctive 0
> 2012-11-12 14:29:12,495 [Process messages received] INFO  com.feed.feedReceive.ProcessFeedStreamLine - Successfully received a message from the feed
> The number of items in the map from senders persepctive 0
> 1 :the size of the map now someone has added
> 2012-11-12 14:29:15,495 [Process messages received] INFO  com.feed.feedReceive.ProcessFeedStreamLine - Successfully received a
> ```
>
> message from the feed
>       The number of items in the map from senders persepctive 0

New code for Singleton

```
public class ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton {

    private static ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton instance = new ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton();
    private volatile ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> tickerToNumberRegistered = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer>();

    protected ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton() {
         // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
    }

    public static synchronized ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> getTickerToNumberRegistered() {
        return tickerToNumberRegistered;
    }

    public void addToClienets(String ticker){}

    public void removeFromClients(String ticker){}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Do you safely instantiate the ConcurrentMap? I.e. as a final field inside a static block? Is there lazy initialization involved? Post at least the initialization logic and mutating accesses.

Comment: sorry - i have added the code

Comment: Try making getInstance() synchronized - otherwise this can lead to two different "instance" instances.

Answer (score 3):

There is a race condition in the posted code that can result in more that one instance of the singleton being constructed if two threads call `getInstance()` and the singleton has not yet been constructed:

```
public static ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {                                   // Line 1
        instance = new ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton();     // Line 2
    }
}
```

A possible execution of two threads, `T1` and `T2`:

- T1 peforms check at line 1 and enters `if` branch.
- T1 is suspended, with `instance` still being `null`.
- T2 peforms check at line 1 and enters `if` branch.
- T2 constructs class and assigns to `instance`.
- T2 returns `instance` to caller.
- T2 is suspended.
- T1 is started again and constructs another instance and assigns to `instance`.

The construction of the single instance must be threadsafe. Possible solutions would be:

- Make the `getInstance()` method `synchronized`.
- Don't use lazy initialization (if possible):

  ```
  private static final ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton instance =
      new ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton();
  ```

Comment: @SkyR, apology unrequired. Just to be sure, you definitely performed a rebuild and are executing the new application?

Comment: Yes - just did a clean, refresh and rebuild to make sure! ive just put some code output in to the original message

Comment: it must be the same instance that is being used becausei created a random int in there and then printed this from two differenct threads and it prints the same number

Comment: @SkyR, from the code it looks as though the internal map can be replaced. Is it possible the two threads are actually accessing different maps because of a swap? BTW, the member `tickerToNumberRegistered` needs to be marked `volatile` if it can be reassigned to ensure the assignment is visible to other threads.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to help. I have already added volatile key word to the variable and also the setter has been removed. it was not needed i just accidentally created it via the eclipse wizard.

Comment: @SkyR, could you add your new code to the question (don't replace the original code as that will confuse anyone coming to the question) or uploaded somewhere else (pastebin or ideone for example)? I am unsure what the cause is.

Comment: hmjd - i have added my most recent singleton class

Comment: I have also not mentioned that two classes sub class this class and they are both generated by Java Spring

Comment: @SkyR in Spring, singletons are beans residing in the container, typically they are not *Java* singletons. So basically they are just thread-safe objects.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov could this be the problem then?

Comment: @SkyR it has nothing to do with the problem, this will be significant when you will add them to the container

Comment: ok it works if i make the variable public and static :) maybe it will work if i just make it static

Comment: @SkyR Spring  beans are already singletons(as there is typically only  one bean instance of desired type in the container) - it's absolutely useless to implement singleton pattern for them. What you likely need is just a simple thread-safe class. I.e. without static fields at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19436/discussion-between-boris-treukhov-and-skyr)

Answer (score 0):

Define your hash map as

```
private volatile ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>
```

The volatile keyword warns the JVM that the state of the variable may be changed by another thread at any time, so it must not be cached locally.

Defining the instance also as volatile might also be necessary.

Comment: 1- volatile will only make changes to tickerToNumberRegistered trigger reconciling cpu cache with main memory but changes to the map itself won't do that 2- ConcurrentHashMap itself is responsible of making changes visible to all threads accessing it.

Comment: the problem with this code is not that the changes with the map will not be synchronized - that is not the case. The problem is that the map still can be initialized twice as shown in @hmjd answer - so basically the users will see different instances of the registry and data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of DCL antipattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_checked_locking

```
public class ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton {

    private static volatile ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton instance = null;

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> tickerToNumberRegistered = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer>();


    private ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton() {
         // Exists only to defeat instantiation. 
         // please not that constructor should be private
    }

    public static ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton getInstance() {
         if (instance == null) {
               synchronized(ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton.class){
                  if(instance == null)
                    instance = new ClientRegistryDetailsSingleton();
               }
         }
         return instance;
    }

    //You should not break encapsulation and allow a link to HashMap escape
    private void setTickerToNumberRegistered(ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> tickerToNumberRegistered) {
        this.tickerToNumberRegistered = tickerToNumberRegistered;
    }

    //You should not break encapsulation and allow a link to HashMap escape
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> getTickerToNumberRegistered() {
    }

     //I omitted the access to the hash map it's likely that some additional params required
     public void addToClienets(String ticker){}

     //I omitted the access to the hash map it's likely some additional params are required
     public void removeFromClients(String ticker){}
}
```

I've shown this only as a synchronization example, in real life you should likely implement your singletons as Enums : [What is the best approach for using an Enum as a singleton in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427902/what-is-the-best-approach-for-using-an-enum-as-a-singleton-in-java)