# In Enum, why I have to declare enum constants at first place, why not any method or variables?

Tags: java, enums

```
  package enum_movies;

   public enum Show_Day 
   {
        MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY;
   }
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392885/java-definition-of-methods-and-variables-inside-enums-constant

Comment: Do you mean, why do you need to declare the enum constants before defining any methods?

Comment: Yes Ted, that's my question is.

Comment: my concern is only about, why constants has to be in first line!? why not any member at first line n later I will declare the constants? why the syntax is made like that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't *have* to.  All the JLS requires is that [there be an enum body with constants defined *first*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), and it's legal for that body to only contain a semi-colon.

You *could* have an enum with all static methods in it like such...

```
public enum Baz {
    ;
    public static void evilLaugh() {
        System.out.println("BWAHAHA");
    }
}
```

...but what's the point of an enumeration if there are no values to enumerate over?

Comment: my concern is only about, why constants has to be in first line!?
why not any member at first line n later I will declare the constants?
why the syntax is made like that?

Comment: ...Because the language specification said so.  I believe I provided a link to the specific specification in my answer too...