# How to create a method which used by 3 Activities

Tags: java, android

I create `methodAbc()` for getting network information. `Context` is required in this method.
I want to use this method for 3 Activities.

How can I implement it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763610/using-single-class-in-multiple-activities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is two option right now i can see.

1. Create a `BaseActivity` which will consist the method .. all the `activities` will extend from `BaseActivity`
2. Simply create a Util static method passing a `Context` as parameter

Answer (score 2):

You can always access a `public` method from any class. You just have to create an instance of that class, and then call the method on that instance. For example:

```
public void methodAbc(Context c) {
    // do stuff
}
```

and then reference that method like so:

```
YourClass x = new YourClass(yourClassParameters);
x.methodAbc(yourContext); // yourContext might be getApplicationContext()
```

---

That, or you could make the method `static`. Although, you may not be able to make your method `static` if it has calls to other `non-static` class methods. Assuming that it can be made a `static` method, though:

```
public static void methodAbc(Context c) {    
    // do stuff
}
```

and then you can call it from another class, like this:

```
YourClass.methodAbc(yourContext); // yourContext might be getApplicationContext()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public void myMethod(Context context) {
//etc etc
}
```

Now from any class just refer to it as `MyClass.myMethod(this);`

Comment: how can you get context from a static method

Comment: no .. i am calling about making the method static .. like public void MyMethod ..

Comment: I wouldnt recommend making the method static, calling non-static methods would not work with it

Comment: it is not must .. just suggested if possible .. usually utilities methods are easy to use if it is static