# Enum class initialization in Java

Tags: java, enums, initialization

In Java we can do the following to initialize class and call method inside that class:

```
public class MyClass {
  public String myClassMethod() {
    return "MyClass";
  }
}
```

.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); // initialize MyClass
    myClass.myClassMethod();// call a method      
  }
}
```

If my class is an `enum` class, implementation will be the following:

```
public enum MyEnumClass {
  INSTANCE;
  public String myEnumClassMethod() {
    return "MyEnumClass";
  }
}
```

.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyEnumClass myEnumClass = MyEnumClass.INSTANCE;
    myEnumClass.myEnumClassMethod();
  }
}
```

Both of these cases works in the same way, but it is said to be better in the `enum` implementation. My question is why and how it is happening?

Comment: Who says, that an enum implmentation is the "better way"? Classes have their needs, as well as do enums.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose refer answers here

Answer (score 14):

An `enum` is essentially a singleton pattern.

The JVM handles the initialization and storage of `enum` instances. To see this most clearly you can write:

```
public enum MyEnumClass {
    INSTANCE("some value for the string.");

    private final String someString;

    private MyEnumClass(final String someString) {
        this.someString = someString;
    }

    public String getSomeString(){
        return someString;
    }
}
```

And in another class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final MyEnumClass myEnumClass = MyEnumClass.INSTANCE;
    system.out.println(myEnumClass.getSomeString());
}
```

This would print out "some value for the string.".

This demonstrates that the `enum` instances are initialised at class load time, i.e. as if by the `static` initialiser.

Or put another way:

```
new MyClass() == new MyClass();
```

Is **always `false`**, whereas:

```
MyEnumClass.INSTANCE == MyEnumClass.INSTANCE;
```

Is **always `true`**. i.e. `MyEnumClass.INSTANCE` is **always the same** `MyEnumClass.INSTANCE` whereas **a new `MyClass`** is created every time your call `new MyClass()`.

This brings us nicely to your question of "better".

An `enum` is a singleton instance with various nifty methods for converting `String` `enum` names into a reference to the singleton instance that it represents. It also guarantees that if you de-serialize an `enum` there won't be two separate instances like there would for a normal class.

So an `enum` is certainly much better as a robust and threadsafe singleton than a `class`.

But we cannot have two instances of `INSTANCE` with the different values for `someString` so the `enum` is useless *as* a `class`...

In short `enum`s are good for what they're good for and `class`es are good for what they're good for. They are not substitutes and therefore cannot be compared in any meaningful way expect when one is used as the other.

Comment: No, enum can be used as a singleton pattern, but that's a side effect. Enum is just an enum.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea `enum` can be used as a singleton pattern because it is a singleton, hence it implements the singleton pattern. You can hang some other singleton values off of the `enum` but that's neither here nor there.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple implementation of the Singleton pattern, relying on the mechanisms of how Enum's work.

If you use `MyEnumClass.INSTANCE` a second time, you'll get the same object instance.

In contrast, `new MyClass();` will create a new object.

See also discussion here:

[What is the best approach for using an Enum as a singleton in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427902/what-is-the-best-approach-for-using-an-enum-as-a-singleton-in-java)

There would possibly be more to learn by reading [Java Language Spec Section 8-9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)