# Enum type initialized confusion in Java

Tags: java, enums, initialization

```
public enum itemType{
  COMPANYY_WIDE("Company"),
  DEPARTMENTAL("Departmental"),
  PROJECT_SPECIFIC("Project");

  private String itemCode;

  private itemType(String dbCode){
      this.itemCode=dbCode;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      itemType type3=new itemType("Project");// line 1 
      itemType type2=itemType.valueOf("PROJECT_SPECFIFIC");// line 2
      itemType type4=itemType.values()[0];// line 3
      itemType type1=itemType.DEPARTMENTAL;
   }
}
```

So enum itemType has 4 types and each type has an attribute itemcode which is also the dbcode. I try initializing the enum types with different approaches in main but I have some confusion. Why line 1 does not work? Why line 2 and line 3 will work?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971982/enum-class-initialization-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, `enum` is a special type class which has fixed number of object.

For your case, `itemType` has exactly three object named `COMPANYY_WIDE`, `DEPARTMENTAL`, `PROJECT_SPECIFIC`. You cant create any new object at runtime for `enum`.

You could read this Java-Doc [Java Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Nice explanation! since we cannot create new object, what is the meaning of having a constructor inside the enum? @rev_dihazum

Comment: @user6119494 the constructor is used only once to load the item initially.

Comment: Constructor used to set properties of ``enum``. for example if you have another property of your enum type i.e. ``private int itemId;`` then you need to modify your constructor as ``itemType(String dbCode, int id){
    this.itemCode=dbCode; this.itemId = id;
}`` and declare objects as ``COMPANYY_WIDE("Company", 1)``

Comment: "load the item initally" you mean match the type to their item code? @flkes

Comment: @user6119494 , hey! as you accepted it as answer it would be nice to upvote it to appreciate.