# How to perform an expensive one time initialization in a Servlet filter?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

Here are the requirements for the problem:

- java web application running in Tomcat 7
- The initialization code needs to talk to an external database
- The external database might not be available during start-up of the application
- The application start-up can not fail otherwise tomcat will mark the application as not running and will not send the application any requests. Instead the application should start-up accept requests and if it finds that the app specific initialization is not complete it should try to complete it during the request processing.

I am trying to use the servlet filter below to solve the problem. and I have following questions.

- Is this Servlet filter thread safe, will it execute the initialization code only once?
- Is there a way to solve this problem without using a servlet filter?
- Is there a better way to solve this problem?

```
 package com.exmaple;
    @WebFilter("/*")

 public class InitFilter implements Filter 
 {
    private volatile boolean initialized = false;

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("InitFilter.destroy()");
    }

        // is this method thread safe and will only execute the init code once
        // and will cause all requests to wait until initialization code is executed
        // thread code
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            System.out.println("InitFilter.doFilter()");

            if (initialized == false) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    // do expensive initialization work here
                    initialized = true;
                }
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

        public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
            System.out.println("InitFilter.init()");
        }
      }
```

Comment: You can use an `Executors.newSingleThreadPool()` executing a `FutureTask<Foo>`; then you'll access your `Foo` using this `Future`'s `.get()`

Comment: The pattern test-synchronize-set is inherently unsafe because thread-A can test `initialized==false` then be suspended prior to `synchronized(this)` - thread-B then tests initialized, does the synchronization, then starts the init; thread-B is then suspended on I/O and thread-A tries `synchronized(this)` and is blocked because B still has the sync. When thread-B finishes and unlocks thread-A will continue and run the initialization again.

Comment: at the best least  initialized = true; should be first line of code. Better to see singleton pattern and use that, even though its not the best - for academic reasons, in real life apps i have seen this kind of initialization work very well. we connect to do db by pre touching a servlet and have a singleton load resources but the check is more like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427902/what-is-the-best-approach-for-using-an-enum-as-a-singleton-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it as a `ServletContextListener` and run the initialization in the `contextInitialized` method, as a separate thread, maybe using a `FutureTask` as @fge suggests, or a `newSingleThreadExecutor` rather than a pool.

Maybe something along the lines of...

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
{
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // Long running initialization code, or a call to it.
        }

    });

}
```

This avoids problems with synchronization and only runs the initialization once. (Once per Context)

In any case, doing this or a Filter, the rest of your program has to deal with initialization being incomplete.

Comment: So this way the app starts up successfully but how to fail requests that depend on the initialized being complete until the init is complete.

Comment: @ams - to fail requests you could use a Filter, but all it would have to check would be something like an `initiazationComplete` flag; no sync needed or lock contention. You could use an `AtomicBoolean` for the flag, and have the init code set it to true when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to put your long-running initialization in a thread, like:

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
    //Configure logging, app, pool ...
    MyAppStarter.getInstance().start();
}
```