# INSTANCE in Java Enum

Tags: java

For a Java Enum, what does INSTANCE mean (I see we can refer EnumName.INSTANCE for use methods defined in Enum)? Tried to find answer from web but failed.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 6):

Enum values are typically expressed in upper case, `Colour.RED`, `Colour.BLUE` etc.

If you see `INSTANCE` it probably means someone is using the [enum singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427902/what-is-the-best-approach-for-using-an-enum-as-a-singleton-in-java).

Comment: Thanks Duncan, yes, I am talking about singleteon pattern of enum. And what is the benefit of using singleton pattern of enum, comparing to using singleton pattern of a normal Java class?