# INSTANCE in a Java Enum

Tags: java, serialization, enums

It is a good practices to define INSTANCE in an Enum, for the benefit of serialization for free (Effective Java Edition 2, Item 3). If anyone could explain a bit more what it means, it will be great.

[What is the best approach for using an Enum as a singleton in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427902/what-is-the-best-approach-for-using-an-enum-as-a-singleton-in-java)

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: I can't explain something I can't read.  I also don't see how the link relates to the question you are asking.  Please explain the connection.

Comment: Impossible to answer definitively without the text in question, but I'm going to guess that the author is suggesting that the best approach to *create a Singleton* is with an `enum`... However, dealing with `Serialization` can be difficult with a *`Singleton`* that isn't implemented as an `enum` (and you can try it yourself if you like). So the author's assertion does not seem without merit.

Comment: It's generally good practice to do whatever it says in that book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a demonstration:

```
import java.io.*;

class ClassSingleton implements Serializable {
    public static final ClassSingleton INSTANCE = new ClassSingleton();

    private ClassSingleton() {}
}

enum EnumSingleton {
    INSTANCE;
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        byte[] data;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(output)) {
            oos.writeObject(ClassSingleton.INSTANCE);
            oos.writeObject(EnumSingleton.INSTANCE);
            data = output.toByteArray();
        }

        try (ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(input)) {
            ClassSingleton first = (ClassSingleton) ois.readObject();
            EnumSingleton second = (EnumSingleton) ois.readObject();

            System.out.println(first == ClassSingleton.INSTANCE);
            System.out.println(second == EnumSingleton.INSTANCE);
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have both a "simple" class-based singleton, and the enum-based version.

We write out both instances to an `ObjectOutputStream`, then read them back again. The output is `false` then `true`, showing that with the class-based singleton, we've ended up with *two* instances of `ClassSingleton`... our "normal" one, and the one created by deserialization. We only have one instance of `EnumSingleton` however, because enums have serialization/deserialization code to preserve their "fixed set of values" nature. You can write this code for the class-based singleton too, but it's easier not to have to.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, what is the benefit of one instance (in the case of Enum)?

Comment: @LinMa: Well it's not a singleton if there are multiple instances :) You end up with reference equality and lower memory use.

Comment: it makes senses, and if a program runs to complete (JVM shutdown) and then restarts (a new JVM instance), how single instance helps in this scenario (start a new JVM)?

Comment: @LinMa: No, it's a single instance within a JVM, whether that instance has been obtained via deserialization or just using `EnumSingleton.INSTANCE`.

Comment: want to confirm with you INSTANCE in ENUM only helps in single SVM to control only one instance is created?

Comment: @LinMa: Assuming you meant JVM, then yes - that's basically the definition of a singleton.