# Is this Singleton a thread safe one ? I can't see how?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton

Consider the Singleton :

```
public final class MySingleton {
    private static class Nested 
    {
        private static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();
    }

    private MySingleton() 
    {
        if (Nested.INSTANCE != null) 
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already instantiated");
        }
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance() 
    {
        return Nested.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

I didn't put any locks , but why is this a thread safe solution for the Singleton problem ?

Comment: Why don't you use an `enum` instead?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza How?!

Comment: @HannoBinder [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java). Also [What is the best approach for using an Enum as a singleton in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427902/what-is-the-best-approach-for-using-an-enum-as-a-singleton-in-java)

Comment: Ah. I overlooked that an `enum` can have fields and methods like a normal class. Still, I wouldn't use it for singletons (no inheritance &c. for enums).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I didn't put any locks, but why is this a thread safe solution for
>   the Singleton problem ?

Because class variables are initialized when their declaring classes are initialized and classes are initialized behind a lock. The process is described in the [Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) chapter of the Java Language Specification.

When your client code invokes `getInstance`, the corresponding thread will try to access `Nested.INSTANCE`. If `Nested` hasn't been initialized, the current thread will acquire an initialization lock for the class and initialize it. Part of the initialization process will initialize the `final` class field `INSTANCE`.

Note that in the example you have given, there is no point in having the `Nested` class be a holder for `INSTANCE`, you might as well have had the field in the `MySingleton` class.